# Webpack error on save even if nothing has been modified

Tags: typescript, webpack, webpack-dev-server, pixi.js

And I'm working on a project with pixi js using typescript. When I compile everything is fine but as soon as I save, even if I haven't modified anything, I get this error "The loaded module contains errors
at ..\node_modules\webpack\lib\dependencies\LoaderPlugin.js "

can someone help me?

Comment: What do you mean 'when you save'?  And what are the errors?

Comment: I mean when I save a file. Normally it should recompile automatically and it did sometimes, but now  LoaderPlugin.js started throwing me the error that says "The loaded module contains errors"  but there are no errors in the code, otherwise it would not have compiled even the first time

Comment: We're going to need way more information about your project, the webpack config, and how everything is set up to even begin to help debug this. [how to ask a good question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)